# Trying to connect PHP to Hana DB through ODBC

Tags: php, odbc, hana

I am trying to connect to my Hana DB using PHP 7. 
Message returned is:

***PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect***

This is what the ODBC Data Source Administrator looks like:
[image]

[image]

When I test the connection through the ODBC Data Source Admin it is successful.

PHP code:

```
$driver     = "HDBODBC";
$servername = "10.10.10.34";      //tried also hanabone here      
$db_name    = "NDB";                            
$username   = "ABC";                     
$password   = "123";

$connexion   = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;ServerNode=$servername;Database=$db_name", $username, $password,SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

It is probably obvious, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ODBC clearly established (as you see the prompt successful when tested)

For ODBC DSN (data source name) connection , try using PDO instead

```
<?php

   $username = "ABC";
   $password = "123";
   $dsn ="odbc:hanabone";

//For example to get all data from tablename1
 
  $queryString = "SELECT * from tablename1";

   $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare($queryString);
   $stmt -> execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Alternatively, if you are using 32 bit driver and the server is accessed thru port 30015:

```
<?php

$driver     = "HDBODBC32"; 
$servername  = "yourservername.com:30015"; 

$db_name    = "HDB";        
$username   = "ABC"; 
$password   = "123"; 

$conn       = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;ServerNode=$servername;Database=$db_name;", $username, $password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

Comment: Following your direction to correctly write out the connexion statement, brought us to another error which allowed us to find a mismatch in between the PHP app in 32-bit and the 64-bit driver. Thanks.